man what iptables docs for --sport and --dport
It's hard to find the documentaion for --sport and --dport by using "iptables --help" or "man iptables".
iptables --help | grep port
man iptables | grep port

But I can find it from Internet:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables
--source-port,--sport [!] port[:port]
--destination-port,--dport [!] port[:port] 

What's the command for checking the iptables docs for --sport and --dport in offline?
man ?


Perhaps man iptables-extensions has what you are looking for?

Or man -k iptables and man -a iptables.

Also once you've found which man page documents the option you're looking for (in this case steeldriver has it right I think, but in general you can use waltinator's method), you can type / while reading the man page, type down stuff and search for strings (in this case --sport / --dport) within the manpage and (hopefully) quickly get to the relevant section instead of grepping stuff. n for the next result, N for the previous result and g to go back at the start.

dport/sport question.
--dport stands for DESTINATION port. This matches against the target port of the connection.
--sport stands for SOURCE port. This is the port on which the packet originated.
For example, all http connections have DPORT 80 for packets from client->server, and SPORT 80 for server->client.
